# Функция с точкой в названии

Tags: ооп, ruby

Есть класс с обработкой `method_missing()`. Я хочу передать этому классу название функции типа: `func.name(agrs)`. И потом обработать эту функцию в моем классе.

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby identifier может состоять только из букв, цифр и подчеркивания](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_syntax.htm), значит, такой функции не может существовать. Если разговор о методе класса, опять не удастся, так как будет выполнена попытка запросить у класса свойство `func`, а уже у него - метод `name`, в итоге если и будет вызван обработчик `method_missing`, то в том классе, какого типа `func`, а если нет такого `func`, поймаешь ошибку "нет метода в nil", только и всего.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще создать метод с точкой (и вообще чем угодно) в названии **возможно**, с помощью `define_method`. Но и вызвать его тогда будет возможно только с помощью `send`'ов, а не как у вас. Так что вам это ничем не поможет.

Формулировку `obj.func.name(args)` парсер опознает, как цепочку вызовов. Поэтому ваш единственный выход -- заставить `func` возвращать значение с записями "у кого вызвали", "что вызвали", "с чем вызвали" и готовое аналогично отреагировать на вызов `name(args)`.

Ну, или пересмотреть, "так ли это нужно". Это далеко не самые быстрые манипуляции.